# reading and storing a .bmp file in java

Tags: java, bitmap, file-io

I'm am trying to read a .bmp file called `circle1.bmp`. It is in a package that I have imported into the following file.

So far I have the following code, but when I run the following code I get:

javax.imageio.llOException: Can't read input file!

```
public void setUp() throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("circle1.bmp"));
    byte[][] greenInputData = new byte[30][40];

    for (int x = 0; x < inputData.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < inputData[x].length; y++)
        {
            int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            //alpha[x][y] = (byte)(color>>24);
            //red[x][y] = (byte)(color>>16);
            greenInputData[x][y] = (byte)(color>>8);
            //blue[x][y] = (byte)(color);
        }
    }
    this.inputData = greenInputData;

    System.out.println(this.inputData);
}
```

Comment: ImageIO claims to have support for BMP http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html however, I think there's a lot of variability in bmp files and it doesn't handle very many of them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try something like

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/your/file.bmp"));
```

Comment: BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(                       "C:/Users/Quinn/workspace/WalnutIQModel/src/vision_data/circle.bmp")); is giving me the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: When using getResourceAsStream(), you must use a relative path.  Try "/visiondata/circle.bmp"

Comment: I tried the relative path "/vision_data/circle1.bmp" and now I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Nope. javax.imageio.IIOException: New BMP version not implemented yet.

Answer (score -1):

Likely your image's file path isn't correct relative to the user directory. To find out where Java is starting to look, where the user directory is, place something like this line of code somewhere in your program:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Perhaps you'd be better off getting the image as an InputStream obtained from a resource and not as a file. e.g.,

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("circle1.bmp")); //prefered
```

or

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("circle1.bmp"));
```

This will look for the image at the path given relative to the location of the class files, and in fact this is what you must do if your image is located in your jar file.

Comment: Nope. javax.imageio.IIOException: New BMP version not implemented yet.