# PNG to Bitmap file conversion

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm developing a RESTful API with Spring where some users can upload some images they draw in a mobile device. The mobile application sends the image in .png format and I would need to generate a bitmap from it for further processing in Delphi. I've been playing around using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class but it does not seem to do the trick when specifying .bmp format and writing to a new file. Are out there some libraries that do these kind of image conversions? It should be a solved problem nowadays but I am not familiar with image processing.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110159/reading-and-storing-a-bmp-file-in-java

Comment: PNG images are bitmaps, and Delphi can read PNG files, apparently. Whence the `.bmp` file?

Comment: @reinierpost the Delphi part is lead by another partner, who expects it exactly as a .bmp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
//Create file for the source
File input = new File("c:/temp/image.png");

//Read the file to a BufferedImage
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

//Create a file for the output
File output = new File("c:/temp/image.bmp");

//Write the image to the destination as a BMP
ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", output);
```

Comment: I actually tried this solution but without much success. I receive the .png file but when trying to write it with ImageIO.write method no file is generated

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Do you have permission to write the file?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown and yes, I do have permission to write files in the directory. The only thing comes to my mind is that the png file is corrupted and hence, no file conversion is executed, but then, some exception should be thrown

Comment: As expected, the .png file was not correctly formatted and hence, no possible conversion was applied. @Henrik, as said, your answer should work with correctly formatted files, so I will accept it as a correct answer. Thanks.